# Possible mistake in the Cambridge Mathematics Entrance Exam (STEP)

Tags: functions, trigonometry, rational-functions

I am trying to figure out if there is a mistake in this question or not. The question is as follows
[image]

In the [markscheme page 24](https://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/STEP/Solutions-and-Reports/2016%20Mark%20Scheme.pdf) it is shown that $x= \pm 1$. However, I belive that $x=1$ only. The way I came to this conclusion is that in part (ii) I showed that $y^2+1\geq4(y-1)^2$ by writing $$y\cos \theta-\sin \theta =\frac{y}{|y|}\sqrt(1+y^2)\cos(\theta + \phi)\leq\sqrt{1+y^2}$$ where $\tan (\phi)=\frac{1}{y}$ and then squaring to get the desired inequality. So if we have the scenario in (iii) it is implied that equality occurs and hence solving for $x$ in the original equation for $y$ gives
$$x^2(1-y)+x(\cos \theta - y\cos \theta) + 1-y=0$$
$$\implies x=1 \quad \text{using the above for the trig coef of $x$}$$

The markscheme seems to have said that since the given information in $(iii)$ implies equality we have
$$(y\cos \theta-\sin \theta)^2 =1+y^2 \implies y\cos \theta-\sin \theta =\pm\sqrt{1+y^2}$$
however, as shown previously, this can only occur when $y<0$ and in this part of the question we are given $y=\frac{4+\sqrt{7}}{3}$ and hence $y>0$ implying the positive root only, and hence, one solution. I went on to plot some graphs on desmos and it seems like there are no such graphs that $y=\frac{4+\sqrt{7}}{3}$ when $x=1$ and $x=-1$. Here is one

[image]

I tried plotting a 3d diagram on wolfram to see if I am correct, however, it is still loading.

I am probably mistaken somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out where. If anybody can assist me I will be very thankful.

Comment: Without looking at anything really, I would guess that $x=+1$ corresponds to the right-hand-side  bound of $y$, and $x=-1$ to the left-hand-side.

Comment: @uniquesolution thank you for your comment. In my question I have discussed that and I have discounted the left-hand side bound.